# Limit of supremum norm of a series of functions that converge pointwise

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose $\{f_n\}_{i = 1}^\infty$ is a sequence of bounded functions $[0; 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, that converges uniformly to $f$. Does that imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\|f_n\right\|_{\infty} = \left\|f\right\|_{\infty}$?

I think that it has something to do, that the uniform convergence is exactly the convergence in supremum norm. However, I do not know how to apply this fact in order to prove this statement...

Answer (score 2):

$ |\|f_n\|-\|f\| |\leq  \|f_n-f\| \to 0$ by the reverse triangle inequality so $ \|f_n\|\to \|f\|$

Comment: ah i see, very good to know, thanks so much

Comment: is this true if pointwise convergence and not uniform convergence? surely not right?

Comment: @sam_aitken_223 Surely not!